# To make default selection in autocomplete (material)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using autocomplete component(i,e Display value autocomplete) for my project.Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mkyeqjagjya?file=app%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts) example

How can i set a any one list item as default ? like this
[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use FormControl SetValue method to set Default Value

```
this.myControl.setValue( {name: 'Mary'});
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8r153h

Comment: @Chellappan, how about passing different value and text ?

Comment: you mean different key value pair?

Comment: The stackblitz doesn't appear to be setting a default value

Comment: @brt it is working fine in stackblitz

Answer (score 6):

set Initial value of `FormControl`

```
myControl = new FormControl({name: 'Shelley'});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RxJs' `tap` operator : [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8r5ytq?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith<string | User>(''),
        map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
        map(name => name ? this._filter(name) : this.options.slice()),
        tap(() => this.myControl.setValue(this.options[0]))
      );
  }
```

Comment: Thank for you help.

Comment: This example is not filtering the values on typing the values.