# Angular Material Autcomplete: set selected value from input

Tags: angular, angular-material

Consider the simple [example on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7zjcun?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-display-example.ts). I have a simple auto complete with 3 `object`s in the `options` list. The input box does not hold an `object` but a regular `string`.

When I first open the box, nothing is selected, even though the input box holds the value `'Shelley'`. When I then open the box and click on anything, than the box closes. When I reopen that box, we see that the previously clicked item is now selected (which makes sense).

But the question now is: **How can I set the initial selection**? I assume it may have something to do with the input box holding a text whilst the `options` list consists out of objects?

But I also cannot give an object to the input box as that would yield `'[Object object]'`.

I also tried using the `onAutoCompleteOpened` event and then loop through the `MatAutocomplete.options`

```
if (option?.value == this.input.value) {
  option?.select();
} else {
  option?.deselect();
}
```

But the issue with this is that selecting in code automatically closes the `MatInput` (not in the first time but on each consecutive open). So a workaround to this method, which is less preferable, is to not have it close when selecting from code.

Comment: This should answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033540/to-make-default-selection-in-autocomplete-material

Comment: Thank you for the response but unfortunately it does not apply to my scenario. They work with form controls which I do not do necessarely. I have a custom control which can be used within a form or without one. 

A second reason why it does not apply is that even in my case where I use forms, they store objects in their form itself, whereas I display one string (e.g. 'Shelley') and store another one (e.g. UserId='U001'). But i still do not store the object itself